# Does this Regular expression accept empty string? a*b*b (a+ (ab)*)* b*

Tags: python, regex, regular-language, finite-automata

In one of my textbook, it says that the regular expression:

```
a*b*b(a+(ab)*)*b*
```

accepts epsilon.

But what I am thinking is since the `b` in it does not have any `*` associated with it, it is surely going to be in the final expression.

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You are correct, `b` should be in the minimal acceptable string

Comment: you are right. b is the shortest one, but your question has nothing to do with python

Comment: See [here](https://regex101.com/r/UCIbDY/1). Empty string does not match.

Comment: What book did you get the regex from? Have you searched for an errata of the book to see if it's a known problem? If the book is relatively new, perhaps you should report it to the author so an errata could be made?

Comment: And do the regex also contain the *spaces* you show here? Spaces needs to match as well.

Comment: There’s a big difference between `a*` and `a\*`. Please double check your question is still correct after the edits.

Comment: Paste your regex at http://regex101.com and you shall see.

Comment: You can also check your regex on e.g [regex101.com](https://regex101.com)

Comment: This is what your regex will match : https://regex101.com/r/g72Baa/1 . And no it wont accept empty strings.